# Run application from network drive takes long

Tags: networking, performance, time, execution

This problem started recently, and I wasn't able to find a solution. Not even formatting solved.
We have a program on our network drive and the Whole company accesses to this single exe. Usually the program starts up in a few seconds except for one computer. On this one computer it takes about a minute to start and in this minute the network card is between 90% and 100% busy, as if it was downloading the Whole folder to some local folder.

Things i have tested:

- Formatting
- Running as administrator
- Adding file path to intranet secure sources in browser settings
- Running in compatibility mode
- Changing user and trying with another one
- changed all lan cables to exclude network problems
- Tried different network card

Facts:

- The pc is running Windows 8.1 Pro with latest updates.
- The PC has a gigabit ethernet connection so network speed is not the cause
- The PC is powerful and should have no problems running the program.
- Other PCs in the lan use the same OS and have no problems.
- Other PCs in the lan have a slower interface (100 mb) and have no problems
- The app is the same since 6 months, and it used to work fine until 2 months ago

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you also check network statistics for any problems? this smells a bit like collisions/MTU problems to me...

Comment: yep, no collision, all other network activity is fine.

Comment: At this point I'd want to run a tcpdump/snoop while opening the application, both on the malfunctioning PC and on a working one, to compare what is actually happening.